# Grouping maven dependencies across projects

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, module

I have a multi-module project where there are various components which follow a fairly standard layout. For example:

```
      root (pom)
          ...
          module-NN (pom)
             module-NN-launcher (jar)
             module-NN-runtime (jar)
          ...
```

(where there are many module-NN projects)

Each *-launcher project uses a proprietary API to launch a framework providing a generic API. The *-runtime projects are then loaded into this framework to "do stuff".

As things currently stand, I have dependencies for the launcher defined in each *-launcher/pom.xml. Likewise, I have the generic APIs references in the *-runtime/pom.xml. I could update the project structure to be something like:

```
    root (pom)
        launcher (pom)
            ...
            module-NN-launcher (jar)
            ...
        runtime (pom)
            ...
            module-NN-runtime (jar)
            ...
        applications (pom)
            ...
            module-NN (pom)
            ...
```

And put the relevant dependencies in the launcher/runtime pom.xml files, but this makes the layout of the projects much less intuitive.

Has anyone faced this sort of problem before? What advice can you provide in producing a meaningful layout without duplicating details across similar projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something about 90% similar.

Consider creating a project called "runtime-common". In that pom.xml, add all the runtime dependencies that are common to runtimes.

In the pom.xml for module-NN-runtime, add this

```
  <parent>
      <groupId>FOO</groupId>
      <artifactId>runtime-common</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>
```

Anything you add to runtime-common will be added to the child projects for runtime-common. This doesn't effect the root project's ability to build all the modules.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
ROOT (POM)
  Launcher-COMMON (POM)
    ...
  Launcher-1 (Jar)
    ...
  Runtime-COMMON (POM)
  Runtime-1  (Jar)
    ...    
  Runtime-2  (Jar)
    ...
```

You don't actually need to keep the launcher and runtime commons in the project if you don't want there there. In that case, do something like this

```
ROOT (POM)
  COMMON (POM)
    Runtime-COMMON (POM)
        ...    
    Launcher-COMMON (POM)
        ...    
  Launcher-1 (Jar)
    ...    
  Runtime-1  (Jar)
    ...    
  Runtime-2  (Jar)
    ...
```